# pydocumentdb 2.3 x-ms-version header issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using pydocumentdb to connect to the Azure Cosmos DB emulator running locally, all was working fine using pydocumentdb version 2.2.1.  Was advised by my IDE that version 2.3.0 of pydocumentdb was now available, so I upgraded it.  Now when I try to connect to the emulator, I receive the following error:

`{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid API version. Ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed.\r\nActivityId: 0e0acdab-8e0d-409e-b7fe-efec3bed3044"}`

which I am pretty sure should be set to 2017-02-22 but I cannot figure out what changed and/or how to figure out what the client is sending.

Comment: Did you try inspecting your HTTP header using a tool like Wireshark? It may help you. Also, it would be nice if you could tell us more about what you did and add some documentation so we can spend our time helping you instead of searching for relevant information.

Comment: Please include the section of code that generates this failure. Also, have you tried uninstalling pydocumentdb, then re-installing with the version forced to 2.2.1 to verify the problem is what you think it is?

Comment: What is the version of CosmosDB Emulator you’re using?

Comment: Using version 1.17.43.5 of the Cosmos DB Emulator.

Comment: Also did revert back to 2.2.1 and the error went away, so pretty sure it is something going on with 2.3.0 version of pydocumentdb. And the code that triggers the exception looks similar to: `client = doc_client.DocumentClient(
        'https://localhost:8081/', {'masterKey': 'C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=='})
    

    players = list(client.QueryDocuments('dbs/stats/colls/players', {'query': 'SELECT * FROM players p'}))`

Comment: re: wireshark, Cosmos DB requires all traffic to be HTTPS so unsure if I could see much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed.

***My pydocumentdb version is 2.3.0:***

[image]

***My python code:***

```
import pydocumentdb;
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'https://localhost:8081',
    'MASTERKEY': 'C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'db',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'testcoll'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})

results = list(client.QueryDocuments('dbs/db/colls/testcoll', {'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s'}))

print(results)
```

***Output results:***

[image]

It seems that the result is printed correctly.  Is my situation different from yours ? Please post your details of your related code.

In addition , you could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the HTTP request messages.

---

***Update Answer :***

I test the steps using Python 3.6.2 and it works fine too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code causing the issue is the same, I am using python 3.6.2 and it looks like you are using ~2.7, don't know if that would be having anything to do with it.  I will look into Fiddler, thanks!

Comment: @adub45north Please see my update answer. I using python 3.6.2 and it works fine too.

Comment: @adub45north Hi , any progress now?